# SSH into EC2 binding to private IP, not public IP

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ip

I've got an EC2 instance which has been set up to access a secure server via a VPN. The second server will only respond to calls that are bound to the EC2 server's public IP address.

I'm successfully using ssh to access the EC2 instance from my laptop...

```
ssh -i mypem.pem ubuntu@ec2-my-public-ip-address.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but my command line sets up as:

```
ubuntu@my-private-ip-address:~$
```

So, when I try and run a piece of java code on the EC2 server, which makes a call to the secure server via the VPN it is failing because it is using the private IP address as its identifier. The java code can't be provided here, because it is for a secure service, but it has been extensively tested with other examples and on EC2 and we know that there isn't a problem here.

I'm trying to see if there's a way to ensure that any code I execute from the EC2 server uses my public IP address rather than the private IP address is this possible?

Comment: The "my-private-ip-address" string in your prompt is probably the string which the instance is using as its hostname or uname. if that's the case, it's not going to change depending on how you've connected to the host.

Comment: Ok. I sort of expected that (but hoped otherwise), I'm wondering if there's a way to make sure that the java calls bind to the public IP when I run the script.

Comment: What do you even mean by "make sure that the java calls bind to the public IP"? What actual problem are you having?

Comment: The problem is that the VPN between the two servers is set up to accept messages from the Public IP of the EC2 server, and only the public IP. However, when I run the java scripts on the server using ssh, the IP being used is the private IP, I'm trying to understand if there's a way to call the java using the public IP so that I don't have to reconfigure the VPN.

Comment: You say in your question that you're able to connect to the server through ssh to its public IP. So you're able to connect to the server and presumably run commands. Then you say "I run the java scripts on the server using ssh, the IP being used is the private IP". What do you actually mean by this? We don't know anything about this java program that you're running. How is it using this IP address? What is going wrong because it's using the wrong one? Could you [edit] your question to include the relevant code from this program, and the errors that it produces?

Comment: Question updated slightly. I can't provide the Java program as it is for a secure service, but I do make it clear that the java isn't the issue, its the set up of the IP addresses and (possibly) the way I'm accessing the EC2 instance via SSH that means that when I execute code on the command line, the private IP address is what is being used.

Comment: If you can't share code from your actual program, you should consider writing a sample program that performs the relevant action and demonstrates the problem. It sounds like you're using some java class to get the local host's name or IP address, and it's returning a value for the wrong interface. It's very unlikely that this behavior depends on how you accessed the server through ssh. The sooner you stop thinking of this as an ssh problem and start thinking of it as a problem with your java program, the sooner you'll get an answer to your problem.

Comment: Kenster, you were completely right. It was a Java config issue, not an EC2 issue. Thanks for the steer.

Answer (score 0):

The private IP address is the only IP address that an EC2 instance knows about.

The public IP address is translated to/from the private IP by the EC2 network infrastructure using automatic static NAT, so the instance is never actually aware of it.

Check `ifconfig` and you will notice that the public IP is nowhere to be seen.

Yet, if you `$ curl ipv4.icanhazip.com` (or any other "what is my IP?" service), you'll find that your instance's public IP address will always be returned as the address seen by the external service.

Using the private IP internally automatically causes the public IP address to be used when you access the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect `ssh` or `ftp` tools with EC2 instance private IP.

1) You need to create an Elastic IP. Navigate to EC2 service > Network Security.
2) Associate this Elastic IP with EC2 instance private ip.
3) Update inbound rules in security group of your EC2 instance. Add SSH port 22 with source "My IP" option.

Now you can use terminal:

```
ssh ec2-user@<elastic ip>
```

Make user you have installed your EC2 key pair certificate. If not run following:

```
ssh-add -K <.pem file>
```

Comment: I tested the elastic ip address method in the answer, and that works. But why is an Elastic IP needed? SSH'ing with the public dns (instead of ip) worked for me, but SSH'ing into the public IP did not. Why would the public IP address not work?